# C++ If in function not woking

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, void

Im completely new to C++ and Im trying to make my own "cmd". Still getting error: "|11|error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]|"...
Please help :(

Code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void cmd(int command)
{
    if (command == login)
    {
        cout << "Prikaz login neni k dispozici!";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Prikaz ";
        cout << command;
        cout << " neni znamy!";
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Zadejte prikaz: ";
    cin << command;
    cmd(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin << command;` Huh??

Comment: You are trying to return an int value (0) in a function that doesn't return anything (void).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what you are exactly planning to do, but the following program should work. You simply did not declare your integer variables properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int cmd(string command)
{
    if (command == "login")
    {
        cout << "Prikaz login neni k dispozici!";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Prikaz ";
        cout << command;
        cout << " neni znamy!";
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string command; /* Define String */
    cout << "Zadejte prikaz: ";
    cin >> command; /* Input */
    cmd(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to type that in msg :D I want to compare text... If text is "login" then do this, if not then do this :/ How do i do it please?

Comment: @ssasuk1 Adjusted the code accordingly hope it helps. Maybe your should have a look at different datatypes integer, strings, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much :D I just started learning today and I very like it :O Love this community <3 (/^v^)/

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Philipp Braun's answer, the exact issue was that if a function is declared `void`, it can't have an actual return value.  [Specifically, it can only have a return value of type `void`, which basically means it can return either nothing or the result of another function that itself returns nothing.]

```
// Valid.  Function is void, and returns nothing.
void foo(int arg, int u, int ments) {
    doSomethingWith(arg, u, ments);
    return;
}

// Valid.  Returns (with no return value) upon reaching end of function.
void bar(int arg, int u, int ments) {
    doSomethingWith(arg, u, ments);
}

// Valid.  Returns the result of foo(), which itself returns nothing.
void bat(int arg, int u, int ments) {
    doSomethingWith(arg, u, ments);
    return foo(arg, u, ments);
}

// Invalid.  3 is int, not void.
void baz(int arg, int u, int ments) {
    doSomethingWith(arg, u, ments);
    return 3;
}

// Valid again.  Function is int, and returns int.
int quz(int arg, int u, int ments) {
    doSomethingWith(arg, u, ments);
    return 3;
}

// And formally invalid again.  Returns (with no return value) at end of function, instead of returning an int.
// Causes undefined behaviour, which can be... well, anything, really.
int qaz(int arg, int u, int ments) {
    doSomethingWith(arg, u, ments);
}
```

In a function declaration and/or definition, the first type, shown before the name, is the function's return type, and indicates what the function returns.  If it's `void`, the function isn't allowed to have a return value; any `return` statements must either be used without an expression, or with an expression of type `void`.

The `return` statement takes the following form:

```
return /* expression */;
```

In this case, *expression* can be any valid expression (such as in `return 1 + 1;` or `return functionName();`), or can be omitted for functions with a return type of `void`.  Note that it doesn't *have* to be omitted for functions with a return type of `void`; the following is a weird, but perfectly valid program:

```
#include <iostream>

void iReturnVoid() {
    std::cout << "I return void." << std::endl;
}

void andSoDoI() {
    std::cout << "I must inform you that ";
    return iReturnVoid();
}

int main() {
    andSoDoI();
}
```

In short, the type of *expression* has to match the type specified at the beginning of the function.

If a `return` statement isn't explicitly provided, then the function returns upon executing its final statement; this is treated as if the function ends with `return 0;` for `main()`, or as if the function ends with `return;` for any other function.

Also note that if any value-returning function returns without returning a value, whether explicitly by encountering and executing `return;` or implicitly by reaching the end of the function, then it results in undefined behaviour.  (`main()` is immune to this happening implicitly, due to its implicit return statement returning `0`, but can have trouble with this if it encounters an explicit `return` statement without a value.

---

I know this may be a tad complex for your first day programming, but it basically boils down to this:

1. The `return` statement should have the same type as the function itself.  If the function is `void`, it returns `void`.  If the function is `int`, it returns an `int`.  If the function is `char*`, it returns a pointer to a `char`.  And so on.
2. If the program reaches the end of `main()` without encountering a `return` statement, it implicitly inserts a `return 0;` statement to indicate that the program completed successfully.
3. If the program reaches the end of any other function without encountering a `return` statement, it implicitly inserts an empty `return` statement, specifically "`return;`".  This is fine for `void` functions, but can cause problems for functions with any other return type.